# Setting up a foreign key relationship in EF core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

So I have two models. A MovieModel and a MovieQueryModel. Every movie has a corresponding movie query. But movie query does not always have a related movie.

So in my database I would like a column in my movie table that has a reference to the corresponding movie query. But I do not need a column in my movie query table that references a movie.

I originally thought this would be a one to one foreign key relationship but I'm starting to doubt that. It seems for a one to one foreign key relationship in EF I need a reference in both models to the other model.

It seems like I could make the reference to MovieModel from MovieQueryModel and just set it to null for the queries without a match but I don't want to do that. Seems like there is a better way.

Is this a one to one relationship? If not, what kind of relationship is this and how should I setup my models in EF Core to support this behavior? My models are below.

MovieQueryModel.cs

```
namespace imdb_data_retrieval.Models
{
    public class MovieQueryModel
    {
        public MovieQueryModel(string queryTitle, string queryReleaseYear, string result){
            id = Guid.NewGuid();
            QueryTitle = queryTitle;
            QueryReleaseYear = queryReleaseYear;
            Result = result;
            QueryDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string QueryTitle { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string QueryReleaseYear { get; set; }
        public string Result { get; set; }
        public DateTime QueryDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MovieModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using MediatR;

namespace imdb_data_retrieval.Models
{
    public class MovieModel
    {
        public MovieModel(string title, int releaseYear){
            id = Guid.NewGuid();
            Title = title;
            ReleaseYear = releaseYear;
            ImdbId = null;
            QueryDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
        [Key]
        public Guid id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("MovieQuery")]
        public Guid RelatedQuery { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int ReleaseYear { get; set; }
        public string ImdbId { get; set; }
        public DateTime QueryDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it could well be zero-one - to - one relationship.

What you do is at your MovieModel you reference the MovieQueryModelId (and btw what's with the xyzModel, just use Moive without the suffix).

Like so:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using MediatR;

namespace imdb_data_retrieval.Models
{
    public class MovieModel
    {
        public MovieModel(string title, int releaseYear){
            id = Guid.NewGuid();
            Title = title;
            ReleaseYear = releaseYear;
            ImdbId = null;
            QueryDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
        [Key]
        public Guid id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("MovieQuery")] //<-- remove this (EF automatically does it at the relationship stuff)
        public Guid RelatedQuery { get; set; } // <-- remove this
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int ReleaseYear { get; set; }
        public string ImdbId { get; set; }
        public DateTime QueryDate { get; set; }

        //relationship stuff
        public MovieQueryModel MovieQueryModel {get; set;}
        public Guid? MovieQueryModel {get; set;}
    }
}
```

When you add the migration, the EF automatically binds the tables according to the model.
This way every Movie will have zero or one MovieQuery, while your MovieQuery will not need any extra column as per your request.